# Programmically Setting ListBox to scroll to the selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, web-applications

I am working on an asp.net page with C# code behind. This is a webapp !
For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox?view=netframework-4.8

I have a search box for the ListBox. The user enter a few letters and the Listbox is searched for the first item that starts with the search text. It then sets that item to the selected index. This should force the ListBox to scroll, so that the selected item is in view and the user can see items, beginning with the first item that matches the search text. In my case, The first item is highlighted as selected, but there is no scrolling.

Here is some code(.aspx page):

```
   <div id="FindField">
    Type Name or Select from List:<br />
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbxSearch" AutoPostBack="True" onKeyup="reFocus(this.id);" OnTextChanged="txtbxSearch_TextChanged" Width="180" />
 </div>
    
    
    
    <div id="MasterSelector">
      Name&nbsp;&nbsp;Organization<br />
     <%--THIS IS THE RIGHT DROPDOWN--%>
     <asp:ListBox ID="lstbxddNames" runat="server" Rows="15" SelectionMode="Multiple" ondblclick="AddToPersonal();" Width="50%"  />
</div>
```

Found out that ontextchange doesnt fire when the user enters some text. It needs for the form to be submitted before it will trigger. That is why the following function:

```
function reFocus(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).blur();
    document.getElementById(id).focus();
}
```

This function causes the txtbxSearch_TextChanged method in the code behind to fire. Code:

```
>         protected void txtbxSearch_TextChanged(object sebder, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             bool Found = false;
>             for (int i = 0; i <= lstbxddNames.Items.Count - 1; i++)
>             {
>                 string TEST83 = lstbxddNames.Items[i].ToString();
> 
>                 if (lstbxddNames.Items[i].ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith(txtbxSearch.Text.ToUpper())
> && Found == false)
>                 {
>                     lstbxddNames.SelectedIndex = i;
>                     Found = true;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
```

The selected index of the first item that matches is set. However, it never scrolls to it, as every forum post says it should.

Any idea why its not scrolling and a possible solution? My Javascript skills are poor, so if your going to suggest a Javascript solution, your going to have to spoon feed it to me...

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Not sure why you have the refocus function, all its doing it blurring and focusing on every key.  Also, in your textChanged method, have you tried looking at the SelectedValue vs the SelectedIndex?

Comment: The Refocus function is to make the textchange work. The TextBox Web server control does not raise an event each time the user enters a keystroke, only when the user leaves the control.   The function simulates this. As to setting the SelectedValue, it is already set when the Listbox is populated from the Datatable. Setting it again has no effect. From everything I've read, setting the Selected Index is suppose to cause that selected item to scroll within the Listbox to were the user can see it.

Comment: For the refocus you could call a __dopostback from js to get the onkeyup to fire the server side method.  I've always used SelectedValue , does it fall into the selectedIndex loop? Try calling a break; when found=true

Comment: It hits the SelectIndex Loop just fine. It just doesn't scroll to the selected Index.